# reshaping data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n':[0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1],'l':[12 ,16 ,92, 77 ,32 ,47, 22, 14], 'cols':['col1','col1','col1','col1','col2','col2','col2','col2']})
```

and this is what I'm trying to get:

```
col1    col2
l   n   l   n
12  0   32  1
16  1   47  1
92  0   22  0
77  0   14  1
```

I've been playing around with `set_index` and `stack`/`unstack` methods but with no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'n':[0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1],'l':[12 ,16 ,92, 77 ,32 ,47, 22, 14],
     'cols':['col1','col1','col1','col1','col2','col2','col2','col2']})

df['index'] = df.groupby(['cols']).cumcount()
result = df.pivot(index='index', columns='cols')
print(result)
#           l           n      
# cols   col1  col2  col1  col2
# index                        
# 0        12    32     0     1
# 1        16    47     1     1
# 2        92    22     0     0
# 3        77    14     0     1
```

If you care about the order of the labels in the MultiIndex column, you could use
stack and unstack to exactly reproduce result you posted:

```
result = result.stack(level=0).unstack(level=1)
print(result)

# cols   col1     col2   
#           l  n     l  n
# index                  
# 0        12  0    32  1
# 1        16  1    47  1
# 2        92  0    22  0
# 3        77  0    14  1
```

---

When looking for a solution it is often useful to think backwards.

Start with the desired DataFrame and ask yourself what operation might
result in the desired DataFrame. In this case, the operation that came to mind
was `pd.pivot`. Then the question becomes, what DataFrame,
`something`, is needed so that

```
desired = something.pivot(index='index', columns='cols')
```

By looking at [other examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) of `pivot` in action, it became clear than `something` had to equal

```
   cols   l  n  index
0  col1  12  0      0
1  col1  16  1      1
2  col1  92  0      2
3  col1  77  0      3
4  col2  32  1      0
5  col2  47  1      1
6  col2  22  0      2
7  col2  14  1      3
```

Then you see if you can find a way to massage `df` into `something`, *or* again
working backwards, massage `something` into `df`... From this point of view, in
this case, the missing link became apparent: `something` has an `index` column
that `df` lacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `DataFrame.groupby`, `DataFrame.reset_index` and `DataFrame.T` (transpose)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'n':[0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0, 1],'l':[12 ,16 ,92, 77 ,32 ,47, 22, 14], 'cols':['col1','col1','col1','col1','col2','col2','col2','col2']})
print df.groupby('cols').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).drop('cols',axis=1).T).T
```

Output:

```
cols  col1     col2   
         l  n     l  n
0       12  0    32  1
1       16  1    47  1
2       92  0    22  0
3       77  0    14  1
```

Or you can use `concat`:

```
print pd.concat([g.drop('cols',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True) for _,g in df.groupby('cols')],axis=1,keys=df['cols'].unique())
```

Output:

```
   col1     col2   
      l  n     l  n
0    12  0    32  1
1    16  1    47  1
2    92  0    22  0
3    77  0    14  1
```

Hope it helps, :)