# Python DataFrame: transpose one column into multiple column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':['2017-09-27','2017-09-27','2017-09-28','2017-09-29'],'Cost':[100,500,200,300]})
```

How can I get a df like this:

```
2017-09-27   2017-09-28    2017-09-29
  100            200          300
  500            NULL         NULL
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to compute a "cumulative count" of the [items within each group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items). We'll use these values (below) as index labels.

```
In [97]: df['index'] = df.groupby('month').cumcount()

In [98]: df
Out[98]: 
   Cost       month  index
0   100  2017-09-27      0
1   500  2017-09-27      1
2   200  2017-09-28      0
3   300  2017-09-29      0
```

Then the desired result can be obtained by [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [99]: df.pivot(index='index', columns='month', values='Cost')
Out[99]: 
month  2017-09-27  2017-09-28  2017-09-29
index                                    
0           100.0       200.0       300.0
1           500.0         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: I like your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I mean I know cumcount, but why I didn't think of this solution :(. Do you have some articles or books recommend me to read? Thanks!

Comment: Great answer!  I used `cumcount` in a solution that is a derivative of this concept.

Comment: I'm not aware of any book that covers this; to a large extent I think learning these tricks is just a matter of experience. Every time you see something new, learn the trick and take heart: there's only a finite number of them :) PS. Hanging around StackOverflow and trying to answer questions is a great way to learn a subject.

Comment: @ZedFang: I'm sure I'm not the first person to think of this, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21638861/190597) records how I stumbled upon this trick.

Comment: @unutbu： Thanks！

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
`zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s = df.groupby('month').Cost.apply(list)
pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(*s)), columns=s.index)

month  2017-09-27  2017-09-28  2017-09-29
0             100       200.0       300.0
1             500         NaN         NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.concat`

```
pd.concat(
    {k: g.reset_index(drop=True) for k, g in df.groupby('month').Cost},
    axis=1
)

   2017-09-27  2017-09-28  2017-09-29
0         100       200.0       300.0
1         500         NaN         NaN
```

---

**Option 3**
Similar to @unutbu in that it uses `cumcount`.  However, I use `set_index` and `unstack` to do the pivoting.

```
df.set_index([df.groupby('month').cumcount(), 'month']).Cost.unstack()

month  2017-09-27  2017-09-28  2017-09-29
0           100.0       200.0       300.0
1           500.0         NaN         NaN
```