# Python: How to transform a column data csv to row data

Tags: python

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Signal   Channel
 -60        1
 -40        6
 -70        11
 -80        3
 -80        4
 -66        1
 -60        11
 -50        6
```

I want to create a new csv file using those data in matrix form:

```
channel 1 | channel 2 | channel 3 | channel 4 | channel 5 | channel 6 | channel 7 | channel 8 | channel 9 | channel 10 | channel 11
   -60    |           |    -80    |    -80    |           |    -40    |           |           |           |            |    -70
   -66    |           |           |           |           |    -50    |           |           |           |            |    -60
```

But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can manage with, you just have to put the args you want in the to_csv function to make it display as you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data={"Signal":[-60,-40,-70,-80,-80,-66,-60,-50],
      "Channel":[1,6,11,3,4,1,11,6]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['count']=df.groupby('Signal')['Signal'].cumcount()
pivot=pd.pivot_table(df,values=["Signal"],columns=["Channel"],index=['count'])
pivot=pivot.add_prefix('Channel_')
pivot.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.pivot()` from `pandas` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)). First `cumcount` is used to determine the index location for the pivoting.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = """
Signal,Channel
 -60,1
 -40,6
 -70,11
 -80,3
 -80,4
 -66,1
 -60,11
 -50,6"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
df['index'] = df.groupby('Channel').cumcount()
df.pivot(index='index', columns="Channel", values="Signal")
```

gives you

```
Channel    1     3     4     6     11
index                                
0       -60.0 -80.0 -80.0 -40.0 -70.0
1       -66.0   NaN   NaN -50.0 -60.0
```

This answer is adapted from @unutbu's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457655/python-dataframe-transpose-one-column-into-multiple-column)